# KrakenJS - How to set Favicon?

Tags: node.js, express, kraken.js

I've looked into [this issue](https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-js/pull/106), but to no avail.

`app.use(express.favicon('/path/to/icon/'))` also does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using express 4.x, `express.favicon` is no longer bundled with express. You should be using [`serve-favicon`](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-favicon) module or something similar:

```
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
app.use(favicon('/path/to/icon/'));
```

Comment: Which version of kraken js are you using?

Comment: That doesn't seem possible, `kraken-js@0.7.3 wants express@~3.4`. I get peerinvalid error!

Comment: Woops, I'm running `express@3.4.8`.

Answer (score -1):

in your project's /`node_modules/express/bin/express` folder add the path to your favicon inside of `, 'app.use(express.favicon());'`

for example:

```
, 'app.use(express.favicon('path/to/fav/icon));'
```

Comment: they will implement a fix for this in the future. But for now, this is one way of doing it.

https://github.com/paypal/kraken-js/pull/106